# rxjs throttle this.durationSelector is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, ngrx

I am trying to `throttle` ngrx store action updates events with the following code

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/throttle'
import { Dispatcher, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
...
static get parameters() {
  return [[Dispatcher]];
}
constructor(actions$) {
...

this.actions$
  .filter(action => action.type === this.Actions[`LOAD_USERS_REQUEST`])
  .throttle(1000 /* ms */)
  .subscribe(() =>
    ...
  );
```

this throws me an error

> at ThrottleSubscriber.tryDurationSelector (throttle.js:80) TypeError:
>   this.durationSelector is not a function

When I replace `.throttle(1000)` with `.throttle(() => 1000)` it throws a different error that clearly shows throttle expects a function, just not the one that I provide. But I wonder why because the documentation states throttle expects a number value.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/throttle.md

Comment: add this to yours imports `import 'rxjs/add/operator/throttle'`

Comment: of course I did that, otherwise it would have crashed before it could even go into the throttle function

Comment: tried throttleWithTimeout instead of throttle?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Documentation page you're referring on https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS is related to RxJS 4. Since you're using Angular2, you're using RxJS 5.

Operator [`throttle()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-throttle) expects as argument an Observable or Promise.

Operator [`throttleTime()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-throttleTime) takes as argument time in miliseconds.

So you should use `throttleTime(1000)`.

Note that using `.throttle(() => 1000)` is very different. You pass an anonymous function that returns `1000` instead of `1000` number directly. That's why it throws a different error.

Comment: Additional note for searches: this applied equally well to `debounce()` and `debounceTime()`, in RxJS 5.

Comment: see also https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/throttletime.html